# Support Toolbar title/menu vertical centre

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm new to android development and I'm working on an app with ActionBar and Tabs. Recently I switched to the new support library `Toolbar` but the title of the toolbar (ActionBar) isn't vertically centred, while the action buttons are correctly placed.
[Title image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmUPg.png)

The same problem occurs with the first MenuItem in the bar (it's moved up a little bit). [Menu image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWwXX.png)

My activity extends the AppCompatActivty and the layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:orientation="vertical"
                                                 tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>

        <com.myApp.app.views.widgets.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/fragmentPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and the style:

```
 <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  </style>
```

Could someone help me fix this issue? I've searched for a solution but found nothing.

P.S. They were correctly placed as I was using the default action bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `android:theme` rather than `app:theme` here:

```
android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme"
```

Your style should derive from the action bar overlay:

```
<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
...
</style>
```

Consider just using the ActionBar theme directly to start to isolate the problem.